# dont display product in category broadleaf

Tags: solr, categories, broadleaf-commerce

I have a problem with **broadleaf 3.0.6-GA**, it doesn't display product in category.

The method

```
searchService.findProductsByCategory(category, searchCriteria);
```

returns not a full list of products.

I give select from solr:

```
select 
params=
{
    q=*:*
    &fl=productId
    &rows=10000
    &start=0
    &fq=category:10457
    &fq=namespace:d
    &defType=edismax
    &qf=mfg_t+pl_PL_name_t+model_t+pl_PL_desc_t+pl_PL_ldesc_t+
    &sort=category_10457_sort_i+asc&facet=true
    &facet.field={!ex=mfg_s}mfg_s
    &facet.query={!ex=price_p}price_p:[0.00000+TO+5.00000]
    &facet.query={!ex=price_p}price_p:[5.00000+TO+10.00000]
    &facet.query={!ex=price_p}price_p:[10.00000+TO+15.00000]
    &facet.query={!ex=price_p}price_p:[15.00000+TO+*]
}
hits=18 status=0 QTime=234
```

Maybe someone met a similar mistake and can help me with this problem.

Comment: it's impossible to answer this question, do you have access to the Solr admin page? Also, you may not get full list of products, since you have a filter category:10457, which will select only specific category

Comment: Find the product in your solr instance, see what have been indexed for the product and work backwards from there.

Comment: I try run panel at domain:8983/solr/ but it doesnt work. I have error "The connection has time out".
How can I check product in solr instance?
When I check product by query in database, there was all products.
For test I make dump data and run it local. In localhost everything work fine.